# How to run a .java program from another .java program?

Tags: java

I tried it by extending class name of another program and calling it into the main function, when i go to compile and run it, doesn't give an error but also doesn't give an output of another java program it only gives self program output. If this is the wrong way then please describe it here with an simple example.

Comment: by **importing** other programs's class file

Comment: Got it! i was extending it with main class name which is wrong thing to do, now get to know to run a java program from another java program is by extending it's class object name, that is what we call into the main function.

Comment: And thanks  Sujith Karivelil for you reply.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `java.lang.Runtime` and the exec command.

From exec you can run javac and java. I would not recommend doing this though.